# What does makes those methods calls returns those values?

Tags: java, inheritance, interface

I need to write what is the output of those methods calls.

My answer was:

```
I i = new A();
i.m(b);
```

My answer: m_IB because **I** doesn't have any method with a **B** type so I went down to **class A** which implements **I**. **A** doesn't also have any methods with parameter **B** but it extends **I.IImpl** which has a method with m(B b) that prints m_IB.

```
I j = new B();
j.m(b);
```

My answer: m_BB becuase again **I** doesn't have any method with a **B** type so I went down to **class B** because **I j = new B()** and it has a m(B b) which print m_BB.

```
interface I {
  public void m(A a);
    class IImpl {
        public static void m(B b) { System.out.println("m_IB"); }
  }
}
class A extends I.IImpl implements I {
    public void m(A a) { System.out.println("m_AA"); }
}
class B extends A {
    public void m(A a) {
        super.m(a);
        System.out.println("m_BA");
    }
    public static void m(B b) { System.out.println("m_BB"); }
}
public class Interfac {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        A a = new A();
        B b = new B();

        a.m(b); System.out.println(); // m_IB

        I i = new A();
        i.m(b); System.out.println(); // m_AA
        I j = new B();j.m(b); // m_AA m_BA
    }
}
```

Both of my answers are wrong and the correct output is m_AA for **i** and m_AA m_BA for **j**.
I can't understand why I get this output even if I'm calling a method with a type B. 
Both of the correct answer are calling a m(A a) methods.

Comment: what do you think super.m(a); does?

Comment: interview question?

Comment: @Stultuske I know what super.m(a) does but my problem was that I didn't know that I actually call the method provided by the interface and not the overloaded one.

Comment: @CommonMan nope! it's from a Java programming exam!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your interface provides this method:

```
public void m(A a);
```

And your `j` is declared like this:

```
I j = new B();
```

So, yes, it's an instance of `B`, but it is declared as an `I`, meaning, when you call that method, it calls the method provided by the interface, not the overloaded one.

So, in class `B` it takes the method that is provided by the interface:

```
public void m(A a) { // this one
        super.m(a);
        System.out.println("m_BA");
    }

    // not this overloaded one
    public static void m(B b) { System.out.println("m_BB"); }
```

The first line of that method is:

```
super.m(a);
```

Which calls the `m(a)` method in the `A` class, which then prints: "m_AA".
Then, it prints "m_BA"

Comment: Perfect, in the end my problem was that by reading theory I didn't understand that when I call that method, it calls the method provided by the interface, not the overloaded one.
Thank you so much!

Comment: @NoProg if you want the one provided by the class, you'll have to declare j as: B j = new B();, that will do it

Comment: @NoProg if this answered your question, can you mark the question as solved?